# Window.load(function()) not working

Tags: jquery

I can't run the code in my browser.jQuery(window).load(function()) is not working for me..

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>DOM AND WINDOW LOADED</title>
    <script src="http://10.0.1.53/sandbox/jquery_files/js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
        <script src="text/javascript">
            jQuery(window).load(function()
                    jQuery("#sample").html("Height= " + jQuery('#img1').height() + "<br>" + "Width= " + jQuery('#img1').width());   
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="sample">
              <img src="http://10.0.1.53/sandbox/jquery_files/images/JR01441-WGP900_1_lar.jpg" id="img1"/>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: do proper code formatting "enter code here" remove that part & test with another browser also.

Comment: "jQuery(document).ready(function() { " ... One "{" is missing.. not "src=" use "type="

Comment: thank u Rino Raj i got the answer

Answer (score 0):

I would use this technique instead:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    console.log( "ready!" );
});
```

Reference: https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

The reason is the DOM is not accessible when the window has loaded, the DOM has to be processed as well. That is why we wait for the 'document' to be ready (DOM: Document Object Model)

Hope this helps :)

Comment: I'd like to correct you here. The `ready` event occurs after the **HTML document** has been loaded, while the `onload` event occurs later, **when all content (e.g. images)** also has been loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Its not

```
<script src="text/javascript">
```

It should be

```
<script type="text/javascript">
```

and yes you are missing `{` in your `jQuery(window).load(function()`

Comment: Please mark any of the answers as answer to your question which helped you in solving this!

Comment: Guruprasad Rao I can't understood

Comment: You see you have 3 answers posted to your questions!! Mark any answers as right answer by clicking right mark beside to the answer!!

Comment: ya i worked out all three answers. i got the answer Guru :)

Comment: Cool.. The you can appreciate the answers here by upvoting them and accepting anyone of them!!

Answer (score 0):

Curly bracket is missing after function

```
    jQuery(window).load(function() { ** missing **
        **  code here **
    });
```